# Creating multiple users and changing password using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

Currently the GAS UserManager service method contains a method to create a single user? Is there any way to create multiple users at once other than running the createUser method in a loop. I would also like to know if it is possible to *change password* of existing users or *enforcing a password change on next login* possible through GAS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, currently you cannot add many users in a single operation. You have to do it in a loop. 
You can open a request in the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list).

You can use the `DomainUser.setChangePasswordAtNextLogin(true)` function to force password change. [See documentation here.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/domain/domain-user#setChangePasswordAtNextLogin%28Boolean%29)

Comment: I guessed so. I have opened a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2749). 

Thanks for the later half. I completely missed out on that part.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it with GASI; this is based on GAS, but you can use a visual enviroment and loop on a CSV input file.

Comment: GASI does provide those options. But I need to embed the resultant gadget into a google site. An easier approach is to use the google apps dashboard & create the users via CSV. But the persons using the app are purely non-technical. So, the back-end needs to be programmed prior to use.